# net5 self-contained exe misses some system DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I am migrating a medium-sized Win10 app (.NET Framework 4.8) to net5-windows. The solution contains about 30 projects.

While the migration process worked rather straightforward in Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.8.3) the only problem remained to package everything in a self-contained exe. Instead of struggling with the project entries in VS, I am using the command-line method discussed by [Scott Hanselmann in his blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-make-a-winforms-app-with-net-5-entirely-from-the-command-line-and-publish-as-one-selfcontained-file). This also worked smooth and produced an exe of about 140MB size.

One issue remains: Not all of the system dll's are included in the exe. The following ones have to be copied manually to the directory of choice:

[image]

Without these DLLs the app does not work.

My question: What is the reason for this behavior, and how can these dll's be included in the self-contained exe?

Comment: At the end of article you can see a `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` and `IncludeAllContentForselfExtract` properties. Did you try to use them? Linked github issue leads you to [single file design document](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md#user-experience)

Comment: Indeed! This seemed to solve the issue. I never expected those to be native! Now the self-contained has 15MB more. Thanks. If you write it as an answer I can vote your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include a system DLLs into single file app you should use `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` property or `/p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true` switch for `dotnet publish` command, as mentioned in single file publish [design document](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md#user-experience)